# Why is list of objects giving "Illegal Parenthesized Reference" error when adding to it via LotusScript agent?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

Have this line of lotusscript code in an agent that gives an "Illegal Parenthesized Reference: Items" error:

```
Set tempObligor.Facilities.items(Cstr(facilitydoc.requestnum(0))) = tempFacility
```

Facilities.items is defined as a list of objects.

So not getting why error is being thrown by the Notes 8.5 designer.

Equally odd that this worked without problem in Notes 8.0.2.

Code that makes up the objects is below.

Let me know if you have any ideas.

Believe I can do a work around by using a FOR loop that goes through all values looking for a match... but not knowing why the error is occurring bugs me...

```
Dim tempObligor As Obligor 

'This line errs out - does not like () after .items 
Set tempObligor.Facilities.items(Cstr(facilitydoc.requestnum(0))) = tempFacility 

Class Obligor As CollectableObject 
        Public Facilities As SortableList         
End Class 

Class CollectableObject 
        ' STUB 
End Class 

Class SortableList 

        Public items List As CollectableObject 

        Private Sub Sort() 
                Dim uboundarray As Integer 
                Dim nextTag As String 
                Dim x As Integer 
                Dim sortedArray As Variant 

                Dim ArrayToSort() As Variant 

                uboundArray = 0 

                Forall elem In items 

                        NextTag = Listtag(elem) 
                        Redim Preserve ArrayToSort(uboundArray) 
                        ArrayToSort(uboundArray) = NextTag 


                        uboundArray = uboundArray + 1 
                End Forall 

                SortedArray = SortArray(ArrayToSort) 

                Dim TempList List As CollectableObject 
                For x = 0 To Ubound(SortedArray) 
                        Set TempList(SortedArray(x)) = items(SortedArray(x)) 
                Next 

                Erase items 

                Forall elem In TempList 
                        Set items(Listtag(elem)) = TempList(Listtag(elem)) 
                End Forall 

                Erase TempList 


        End Sub 

        Function SortArray(ArrayToSort) As Variant 
                Dim NumberOfElements As Integer 
                Dim temp As String 
                Dim x As Integer 
                Dim y As Integer 

                NumberOfElements = Ubound(ArrayToSort) 
                If NumberOfElements% = 0 Then 
                        SortArray = ArrayToSort 
                        Exit Function 
                End If 

                For x = 0 To (NumberOfElements) 
                        For y = 0 To ( NumberOfElements - x - 1) 

                                If Ucase$(ArrayToSort(y)) > Ucase$(ArrayToSort(y+1)) Then 

                                        temp = ArrayToSort(y) 
                                        ArrayToSort(y) = ArrayToSort(y+1) 
                                        ArrayToSort(y+1) = temp$ 

                                End If 

                        Next y 
                Next x 

                SortArray = ArrayToSort 

        End Function         

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

I pasted your code into a ScriptLibrary. At first I got the same error. Then I noticed that there is another error of type "Reference appears before declaration" in the class definition of class Obligor. Your class Obligor is of type CollectableObject. Domino Designer seems to have a problem with the fact that CollectableObject is referenced before it is defined. So you should place the class Obligor after that class definition and then your code should work (I had to move the first two lines in the initilize though).

Comment: Thanks for testing.  The code posted was copied from a larger set of code - did not paste the elements in the correct order.  My bad.

Will setup like you describe in a test script library and see if it works there.

One theory I have is that "items" defined in SortableList is now a reserved keyword in Notes 8.5...

Comment: Today I came across another code where a variable of name "items" with no error. So I don't think that is the source of the issue. 
It might be a good idea to rebuild the script step by step to see where the first compile error occurs.